# How do you handle country specific behaviors?

Tags: internationalization

I'm currently developping the website of my company, which is located in France.

I always pay attention to giving explicit generic english names to my variables. For obvious reasons, and of course, in order to be able to ship the same code over other countries one day.

For instance I called french "Régions" and "Départements" (which are subdivisions of the country), "Area" and "Subarea". I called companies "[SIRET](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syst%C3%A8me_d'identification_du_r%C3%A9pertoire_des_%C3%A9tablissements)" number, "company_identifier".

However, sometimes there are things very specific to the french legislation. For instance, I need to store the fact that someone benefits from something called "[CPF](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compte_personnel_de_formation)" (Compte Personnel de Formation) in France, but that probably have no equivalent in other countries.

I wonder how I should store this variable, how I should name it. And how to handle this when deploying the website in other countries.

My question is very general (hopefully not too much), the "CPF" example is just... an example.

Another good example is when you want to store the civility of a person. In France, we have "Monsieur", "Madame" and we used to have "Mademoiselle". AFAIK, in UK, there is "Mr", "Mrs", Ms" and "Miss". And other countries have different ways to greet a person according to his gender and social status. Currently, I just store the gender and link it to `ugettext("Monsieur")` or `ugettext("Madame")` when I want to greet a person according to his gender. But I have no idea how I will handle this when I will have to ship my website in another country where this behavior is not accurate (and might offend).

Comment: Note that some of your examples are country specific, others are language/culture specific. You should cleanly separate those.

Comment: You could still put a "CPF verified"-badge on it. Even when they might not know about it might still make the product look better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are too many country-specific issues so in my opinion you cannot handle them in advance.

What I do if I update the code for a new country is to add the ticket number as a comment to the source code so I can easily find all changes that belong to 
the Italian version by searching for the ticket number.

Behavioral changes like "Adress line calculation", "Tax-calculation" are implemented in a country 
specific module that share the same Java interface. TaxCalculation is implemented as TaxCalculationDe, TaxCalculationIt, TaxCalculationFr ...

It gets even more complicated

- if you have countries with more than one language (i.e. Switzerland or Canada).
- if countries have different taxes per region (i.e. Italy with Vatican City and San Marino).
- if countries have more than one timezone (i.e. the U.S.)

Comment: The key information I retrieve from your answer is: Keep the country-specific behaviors outside of country-agnostic modules and create specific modules per country that extend the logic of the main modules. And this is a satisying solution to my problem. Thanks. :)

Comment: That is a good idea in principle, but it's often surprising what details actually are country-specific. So I wouldn't expect that plan to work out perfectly on the first try.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at something as simple as the titulation (monsieur, madame vs. mr., mrs.) it turns out to be very far from simple.

Dr. Frau Merkel and Frau Dr. Merkel has two different meanings. One is a woman married to a man who holds a doctorate, the other is a married woman who holds a doctorate herself. I hope I have them in the correct order.

Leaving out the Dr. can be very insulting in Germany, putting in a Dr. that does not belong there can get you in trouble as well.

Your best bet in all cases is to encapsulate the titulation so that your person class has a titulation property/method, giving you the posibility to later expand the logic without having to change anything in the places where you use the titulation.

And for gender that is a can of worms these days. Don't expect gender to have only two values (male and female) make room for other values.

So use `person.titulation` instead of `ugettext("Monsiuer")`